# subtract single value from part of the column data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like:

```
username    result  sum
user_c  0.20    10
user_a  0.70    100
user_b  0.40    100
user_l  0.43    120
user_e  0.30    130
user_j  0.72    130
user_f  0.25    140
user_h  0.47    140
user_k  0.65    150
user_g  0.43    170
user_d  0.60    200
```

And I want to substract 2 from column **sum** but only from 2-nd row to 5-th, how can I do this?

Comment: `df.loc[2:5, 'sum'].sub(2)` or `df.loc[2:5, 'sum'] -= 2` for in-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.iloc[2:6] = df.iloc[2:6]['sum'].apply(lambda x: x - 2)
```

This slicing will include your 5th row as well. If you don't want to include the 5th row you have to slice `df.iloc[2:5]`.

Comment: In opinion, this is not the best solution.  And, user3483203's suggestion will not work, due to iloc using integer location and 'sum' being a label.  `df.iloc[2:6, df.columns.get_loc('sum')] -= 2`

Comment: Whoops yea, it should be `loc`, not `iloc`.  The advice about `apply` still stands.

Comment: I must say, that I tried using .loc and 'sum' and it worked, maybe I did something wrong since I'm jet-lagged but it wouldn't hurt to check

Comment: @Scott Boston okay I see, I like your solution because it's more readable. But since `.iloc[]` is a Panda Series: in which case would you use `.apply()` then? Maybe when we want to mutate the whole column (or even the whole DataFrame)?

Comment: @Alex There is no need to use apply in this situation, you could do like I did above using += assignment or as Yuca shows.

Answer (score 2):

IUC:

```
df.iloc[1:5,2] = df.iloc[1:5,2] - 2
```

output:

```
 username  result  sum
0    user_c    0.20   10
1    user_a    0.70   98
2    user_b    0.40   98
3    user_l    0.43  118
4    user_e    0.30  128
5    user_j    0.72  130
6    user_f    0.25  140
7    user_h    0.47  140
8    user_k    0.65  150
9    user_g    0.43  170
10   user_d    0.60  200
```